# CSS class of Form elements

Tags: wffm

I'm trying to get all the information of my WFFM Forms in sitecore 7. I could retrieve most of the form info. But unable to identify the css class and styles associated with each field.

I tried to use the class **SitecoreSimpleForm**, but the css class property is null even if the css exists for that item.

[image]

Is there any other way to get the css class value associated with the form elements ?

Thanks in advance..